# Email verification link expires on some computers

Tags: php, email-verification

I wrote an email verification script in php and it works fine for me but when some users click on the link it is already expired.

I investigated and it looks like to me that link is visited by their email client or mail protection service before they click it and hence it gets expired. Is there a way to make sure that link is clicked by user himself instead of a bot or antivirus service.

Comment: Could you require that a CAPTCHA test is completed successfully before executing the action of the link and expiring it?

Comment: may be last option.. I have a second last option too. Send URL without link and ask user to copy/past this url into browser. This might work too but not first option.

Comment: I think some of these ideas have been covered in another question about email verification: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5149061/is-email-verification-with-a-link-a-bad-idea

Comment: Do you really care if they verify it twice? Rather than showing them an error when they've gone there twice, it'd be better to just allow the user to verify their address repeatedly.